# MongoDB Query partially ignoring limit

Tags: node.js, mongodb, limit, mongodb-query

I'm running a query to try and fetch 25 records from a collection with about 3-4k stored records, each rather large. I needed these to be ordered by a specific Id, ascending. So I created this query:

```
var collection = mongoDb.collection('matches');

collection
    .find({
        matchId: {$exists:true}
    })
    .sort({matchId: 1})
    .limit(25)
    .toArray(function(err, docs) {

        /* error management */

        doIf(isVerbose, logger.info, 'Found {magenta:%s} records.', docs.length);

    });
```

The weird issue I had was that it was returning **22** records. When I swapped direction (asc to desc), it returned the full 25.

I looked it up, and saw that it might be better if I add an index for ascending searches, so I added this into the mongo CLI:

```
db.matches.createIndex({matchId:1});
```

And tested it again in my node app. This time (and all attempts afterwards), my query returned with **45** records.

If I change the limit to 20, 21, or 22 they all return nicely - 23 onwards seems to return a large amount than the limit.

What's also odd is that I can run this query in the mongo CLI and it will return 25 records as expected.

I'm wondering if I'm missing something here?

If it's worth anything, here's my collection's stats:

```
> db.matches.stats();
{
    "ns" : "[database].matches",
    "count" : 3678,
    "size" : 910236192,
    "avgObjSize" : 247481,
    "numExtents" : 16,
    "storageSize" : 1069953024,
    "lastExtentSize" : 280522752,
    "paddingFactor" : 1,
    "paddingFactorNote" : "paddingFactor is unused and unmaintained in 3.0. It remains hard coded to 1.0 for compatibility only.",
    "userFlags" : 1,
    "capped" : false,
    "nindexes" : 2,
    "totalIndexSize" : 245280,
    "indexSizes" : {
            "_id_" : 130816,
            "matchId_1" : 114464
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Edit: Requested in the comments.

Here's the explain from the node app (returns 45 results):

```
{ queryPlanner:
   { plannerVersion: 1,
     namespace: '[db].matches',
     indexFilterSet: false,
     parsedQuery: { matchId: [Object] },
     winningPlan: { stage: 'LIMIT',
         limitAmount: 0,
         inputStage:
           { stage: 'FETCH',
             filter: { matchId: [Object] },
             inputStage:
              { stage: 'IXSCAN',
                keyPattern: [Object],
                indexName: 'matchId_1',
                isMultiKey: false,
                direction: 'forward',
                indexBounds: [Object] } } }
     rejectedPlans: [] },
  executionStats:
   { executionSuccess: true,
     nReturned: 1,
     executionTimeMillis: 0,
     totalKeysExamined: 1,
     totalDocsExamined: 1,
     executionStages:
      { stage: 'LIMIT',
        nReturned: 1,
        executionTimeMillisEstimate: 0,
        works: 2,
        advanced: 1,
        needTime: 0,
        needFetch: 0,
        saveState: 0,
        restoreState: 0,
        isEOF: 1,
        invalidates: 0,
        limitAmount: 0,
        inputStage: [Object] },
     allPlansExecution: [] },
  serverInfo:
   { host: '[Host Name]',
     port: 27017,
     version: '3.0.2',
     gitVersion: '6201872043ecbbc0a4cc169b5482dcf385fc464f' } }
```

And here's the one from the terminal (returns 25)

```
    "queryPlanner" : {
            "plannerVersion" : 1,
            "namespace" : "[db].matches",
            "indexFilterSet" : false,
            "parsedQuery" : {
                    "$and" : [ ]
            },
            "winningPlan" : {
                    "stage" : "LIMIT",
                    "limitAmount" : 25,
                    "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "PROJECTION",
                            "transformBy" : {
                                    "$limit" : 25
                            },
                            "inputStage" : {
                                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                                    "inputStage" : {
                                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                            "keyPattern" : {
                                                    "matchId" : 1
                                            },
                                            "indexName" : "matchId_1",
                                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                                            "direction" : "forward",
                                            "indexBounds" : {
                                                    "matchId" : [
                                                            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                                    ]
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            },
            "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
            "host" : "[hostName]",
            "port" : 27017,
            "version" : "3.0.2",
            "gitVersion" : "6201872043ecbbc0a4cc169b5482dcf385fc464f"
    },
    "ok" : 1
```

}

Comment: How about trying to include the limit and sort as query options like `var options = {
    "limit": 25,
    "sort": "matchId"
}

collection.find({matchId: {$exists:true}}, options).toArray(...);`?

Comment: Unfortunately, the same result. Your code still yielded 45 results returned for me. Thanks for showing me that syntax though, wasn't aware you could phrase it that way.

Comment: Can you post an explain for a query where the limit works correctly and for one where it doesn't?

Comment: Edited my original post!